# How to authenticate to Azure Active Directory Protected API from a scheduled Azure Data Factory pipeline

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-data-factory

We are using Microsoft Identity Platform for our Authentication.
We have registered our .NET API (e.g. name of the api = example-api) in Azure Active Directory App registrations.

We are planning to use Azure Data Factory for some data imports/exports.

In this process we need to call this API.

**Problem**
How to call the API from Azure Data Factory pipeline without a user i.e., a scheduled job

Microsoft suggested to use System assigned Managed Identity or User Assigned Managed Identity.

How can I give permissions to the System assigned Managed Identity or User Assigned Managed Identity to access **example-api** which is registered in **AAD app registrations**.

I couldn't find much documentation related apps registered in AAD with managed identity, there is some doc for Users/Groups.

Could someone please help me to solve this issue.

Thank you,
Vamshi

Comment: could you provide your pipeline configurations that you have given for better understanding?

Comment: Hi, sorry I don't understand what do you mean by pipeline configurations? I don't have any configurations.
I need to create a pipeline with just 1 activity i.e. web activity or REST connector to  just call an API that is protected by AAD without any user credentials, 
For info about API 
[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-expose-web-apis)
Web activity info
[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-web-activity#authentication)
I would like to know about managed identity permissions for API

Answer (score 0):

So first thing to be very careful about, and some people run into this problem is the line of sight between tenants and accounts, make sure your registered app or sharepoint or whatever is in the same tenant as the adf. Otherwise adf wont be able to see or authenticate. There might be a way to connect multiple tenants but AAD guys know this better. In your scenario, UAMI is the choice because you can associate multiple resources into UAMI as here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/how-to-view-associated-resources-for-an-identity

While SAMI is easier to use, they are tied to the resources individually. See here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/how-manage-user-assigned-managed-identities?pivots=identity-mi-methods-azp

First link says SAMI cannot be shared across resources. Under 2nd link you can also see how to assign roles and manage access to UAMI.